# Delete and remove the row matching string?

Tags: c#, datatable, delete-row

I want to search for a string in DataTable if it starts with `"null"` delete this string, if this row has no values then erase this row too. Can someone show me how to do it?

```
ID    Name   Comment
2     lola    hallo
5     miky    hi
      null0          // delete null0 and remove this row     
      null1   ko     // delete null1 but do not remove this row
1      hub    why
3     null2          //delete null2 but do not remove this row
```

I tried to delete `"null"` but it doesn't work.

My Code:

```
int ct1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < resE1.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    if(resE1.Rows[i]["SignalName"].ToString() == "null" + ct1)
    {
        resE1.Rows[i].SetField<String>(2, "");
    }
    ct1++;
}
```

I find a solution to replace `"null*"` with empty spaces, but now I want to erase this row if the cells values of this row are empty, how can i do it?

```
int ct1 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < resE1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string fix = resE1.Rows[i]["SignalName"].ToString();

    if(fix.Contains("null"))
    {
        resE1.Rows[i].SetField<String>(2, "");
    }
    ct1++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this. Works for me.

```
List<DataRow> rowsToRemove = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (DataRow dr in resE1.Rows)
{
    if (dr["Name"].ToString().IndexOf("null") == 0)
    {
        dr.SetField("Name", "");
    }
    bool hasValue = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (!dr[i].ToString().Equals(String.Empty))
           hasValue = true;
    }
    if (!hasValue) rowsToRemove.Add(dr);
}
foreach(DataRow dr in rowsToRemove)
{
    dr.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer one of your questions, to delete the entire row do something like this:

```
if(resE1.Rows[i].Contains("null") && (resE1.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() == "") && (resE1.Rows[i]["Comment"].ToString() == ""))
{
    resE1.Rows[i].Delete();
}

bool emptyFlag = false;
if(resE1.Rows[i].Contains("null"))
{
    for(int j = 0; j < resE1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
       if(resE1.Rows[i][j].Equals(""))
        emptyFlag = true;
       else
        emptyFlag = false;
    }
   if(emptyFlag)
    resE1.Rows[i].Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code changed so it works although I don't like how it is written. Check the answer:

```
int ct1 = 0;
int i = 0;
while(i < dt.Rows.Count)
{
    if ( dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString() == "null" + ct1)
    {
        if ((dt.Rows[i][0] == null || dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() == string.Empty) && (dt.Rows[i][2] == null || dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() == string.Empty))
        {
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Rows[i].SetField<String>(1, "");
        }
        ct1++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `DataTable` has column `"Name"` of type `string` you can achieve it like this:

```
private DataTable RemoveUnwanted(DataTable source)
{
    var rowsEnu = source.Rows.GetEnumerator();
    while (rowsEnu.MoveNext())
    {
        ((DataRow)rowsEnu.Current)["Name"] = ((DataRow)rowsEnu.Current)["Name"].ToString().StartsWith("null") ? string.Empty : ((DataRow)rowsEnu.Current)["Name"];
    }

    return (from i in source.AsEnumerable()
            where !(i.ItemArray.All(o => string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.ToString())))
            select i).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

You will also need reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
String test = "Null01";
if (test.IndexOf("Null") == 0)
{
    test = test.Replace("Null", String.Empty);
}
```

For second part of your question, just check if `Comments` are `null` or empty then replace the string too.

Arrange code according to your own requirement.